# How can I merge the numerous data of two columns within the same DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

[here is a pic of df1 = fatalities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzfK4.png)

So, in order to create a diagram that displays the years with the most injuries(i have an assignment about plane crash incidents in Greece from 2000-2020), i need to create a column out of the minor_injuries and serious_injuries ones.

So I had a first df with more data, but i tried to catch only the columnw that i needed, so we have the fatalities df1, which contains the years, the fatal_injuries, the minor_injuries, the serious_injuries and the total number of incident per year(all_incidents). What i wish to do, is merge the minor and serious injuries in a column named total_injuries or just injuries.

```
    import pandas as pd
​    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
    df = pd.read_csv('all_incidents_cleaned.csv')
    df.head()
    df\['Year'\] = pd.to_datetime(df.incident_date).dt.year
    fatalities = df.groupby('Year').fatalities.value_counts().unstack().reset_index()fatalities\ 
    ['all_incidents'\] = fatalities\[\['Θανάσιμος τραυματισμός', 
    'Μικρός     τραυματισμός','Σοβαρός τραυματισμός', 'Χωρίς Τραυματισμό'\]\].sum(axis=1)
    df\['percentage_deaths_to_all_incidents'\] = round((fatalities\['Θανάσιμος          
    τραυματισμός'\]/fatalities\['all_incidents'\])\*100,1)
    df1 = fatalities
    fatalities_pd = pd.DataFrame(fatalities)
    df1
    fatalities_pd.rename(columns = {'Θανάσιμος τραυματισμός':'fatal_injuries','Μικρός τραυματισμός':       

    'minor_injuries', 'Σοβαρός τραυματισμός' :'serious_injuries', 'Χωρίς Τραυματισμό' :    
    'no_injuries'}, inplace = True)
    df1
```

Answer (score 0):

For your current dataset two steps are needed.

First i would replace the "NaN" values with 0.
This could be done with:

```
  df1.fillna(0)
```

Then you can create a new column "total_injuries" with the sum of  minor and serious injuries:

```
  df1["total_injuries"]=df1["minor_injuries"]+df1["serious_injuries"]
```

Its always nice when you first check your data for consistency before working on it. Helpful commands would look like:

```
data.shape
data.info()
data.isna().values.any()
data.duplicated().values.any()
duplicated_rows = data[data.duplicated()]
len(duplicated_rows)
data.describe()
```